# using knockout validation how to do I validate exactly 5 digits and accept empty input

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using the knockout validate plugin and are running into a problem with this scenario

required is false
but if there is input - must be exactly 5 digits

```
    var fileno = ko.observable()
        .extend({ pattern: {
             message: 'not exactly 5',
             params: '/\b\d{5}\b/g'
        }});
```

can anyone see the issue here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation plugin uses the [string.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method internally which expects a [regex object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and if you pass in a string it converts it to an RegExp object with `new RegExp(obj)` but in this case you cannot use flags like `g`

So you need to pass in an already created regex object as the `params`

```
var fileno = ko.observable()
    .extend({ pattern: {
         message: 'not exactly 5',
         params: /\b\d{5}\b/g // or using new RegExp('\\b\\d{5}\\b', 'g')
    }});
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4qbnj/)